# What is "Session Cookie" and what is "Session ID cookie"

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, session-cookies

in ASP.NET scenario

I know session and cookie, but what are "Session Cookie" and "Session ID cookie"? Can anyone explain it to me? What are they and are they mandatory for a web application? Do we set them manually with our own code or .NET framework provides for us?

Comment: Well you've got it all here, briefly a session id is embedded inside the session cookie , url: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/899918

Comment: The ID of the session is stored in the cookie but they are one and the same feature.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean  "Session Cookie" = "Session ID cookie"?  Also in code behind, we have session["x"], session["y"], are these session variables stored in cookie or only on server?